# How to get column names in awk?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, header

I have a data file in the following format:

```
Program1, Program2, Program3, Program4
0,        1,        1,        0
1,        1,        1,        0
```

Columns are program names, and rows are features of programs. I need to write an awk loop that will go through every row, check if a value is equal to one, and then return the column names and put them into a "results.csv" file. The desired output should be this:

```
Program2, Program3
Program1, Program2, Program3
```

I was trying this code, but it wouldn't work:

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i==1) {FNR==1 print$i>>results}; }'
```

Help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk -F', *' '
NR==1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) h[i]=$i; next}
{
    sep="";
    for(x=1;x<=NF;x++) {
        if($x) {
            printf "%s%s", sep, h[x]; 
            sep=", ";
        }
    }
    print ""
}' file
```

outputs:

```
Program2, Program3
Program1, Program2, Program3
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked but for some reason the last field of each row included the very last program name. Using if($x==1) in place of if($x) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=", *" }
NR==1 { split($0,a); next }
{
    out = ""
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
         out = out ($i ? (out?", ":"") a[i] : "")
    print out
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Program2, Program3
Program1, Program2, Program3
```

Answer (score 0):

My take on things is more verbose, but should handle the trailing comma. Not really a one-liner, though.

```
BEGIN {                                                                     
    # Formatting for the input and output files.
    FS = ", *"
    OFS = ", "
}

FNR == 1 {
    # First line in the file
    # Read the headers into a list for later use.
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        headers[i] = $i
    }
}

FNR > 1 {
    # Print the header for each column containing a 1.
    stop = 0
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        # Gather the results from this line.
        if ($i > 0) {
            stop += 1
            results[stop] = headers[i]
        }
    }
    if (stop > 0) {
        # If this input line had no results, the output line is blank
        for (i = 1; i <= stop; i++) {
            # Print the appropriate headers for this result.
            if (i < stop) {
                # Results other than the last
                printf("%s%s", results[i], OFS)
            } else {
                # The last result
                printf("%s", results[i])
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s", ORS)
}
```

Save this as something like script.awk, and then run it as something like:

```
awk -f script.awk infile.txt > results
```